# Add amount option for each variation

Tags: woocommerce

I am building a website that sells products with different variation. I created some variations to the products. However, the variations on the single product show up in a select box.

I want the customer to be able to choose an amount they want for each variation on the same page.

For example:
Chocolate 2x (customer chooses 2 Chocolate variations)
Vanille 3x

I want the customer to be able to buy those 5 flavours in 1 go and that they can select the amount for each variation of the product.

How can we reach this?

Comment: what you're trying to do is grouped product.. not variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you insist on using the variable product and treat it like it's a group, we can do that too.

First we have to remove the hook for the add to cart form of the variable product like so:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

then we have to change it to use the add to cart form of the grouped variable like so:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

in doing so, you'll end up something like this on the front end:
[image: reigelgallarde.me]

take note of the dashes after the quantity input. It's in format `Title` - `Variation`

So this must be it. Then when you're about to do an add to cart it shows like this:[image: Please choose product options…]
It says "Please choose product options…". Why so? This is because the product is of type variable, and we are expected to choose on option. Remember select box.

However, we can fixed it like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler', 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_add_to_cart_handler( $product_type, $product ) {
    // if ( in_array( $product->get_id(), array( 100, 99, 504 ) ) ) {
        $product_type = 'grouped';
    // }
    return $product_type;
}
```

We'll change the product type of the form handler. This way, we're using the grouped form handler and not the variable. Just be careful to put a conditional statements like `if` to only apply to specific products. Or else you'll end up confused between grouped products and variable products if you know what I mean. I've also recklessly did an `add_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 30 );` without conditional statement, I suggest you do.

But once everything is in place, it will look something like this:[image: reigelgallarde.me]

Answer (score 2):

You should use Grouped Product.
[image]

It will look something like this on the frontend.

[image]

Comment: Grouped products seem to be the way to go. However, although they are grouped they are not linked to the product. So in the cart it only shows the simple product of the grouped product and not the parent product like: "Whey protein" (main product) + "Strawberry" (variation). It only shows strawberry. And those variation should be automatically linked to all the parents of the grouped products so that I dont have to create a single unique product for every parent product.